# Return to Home page after Delete function PHP MYSQL JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, alert

Sorry I'm Beginner, I would like to ask if how to go back from Home page or Specific Page after Delete.php it was only a blank page.

**EDIT**

It's look like this after the delete was succesful.

[image]

Here is my code:

**delete.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once 'dbconnect.php';
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM accounts where user_id='$id'");

    if ($sql > 0) {
?>
    <script> alert('Record has been successfully deleted'); </script>
<?php
    } else {
?>
    <script> alert('Database Error!'); </script>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Here is where I call the delete.php function:

```
<td>
    <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['user_id']; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');">
        Delete
    </a>
</td>
```

Comment: @Rahautos is right answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use javascript window.location

```
<?php
   session_start();
   include_once 'dbconnect.php';

   $id=$_GET['id'];
   $sql=mysql_query("DELETE FROM accounts where user_id='$id'");

   if($sql > 0) {
   ?>

  <script> alert('Record has been successfully deleted'); 
window.location.replace("page name");

</script>

  <?php
 } else{ 
  ?>

  <script> alert('Database Error!'); 
window.location.replace("page name");
 </script>

 <?php
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: You're Great, Thank you very much, God Bless You!

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
header('Location:any_page.php');
exit;
```

in delete.php

Comment: ...
<script> alert('Record has been successfully deleted'); </script>
<?php header('Location:any_page.php'); ?> 

Is this Right?

Comment: yes. the any_page.php is your php file to which to gonna redirect. If you are redirecting to home.php which is in the same folder of delete.php. then use header('Location:home.php'); Please make sure you enter correct file with correct path

Comment: Thank you very much. God Bless.